# Get only properties of a Dbpedia subject

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I am currently retrieving information about a subject using following query:

```
DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Albert_Einstein>
```

How can I edit this query to only get information where predicate is dbpedia property (http://dbpedia.org/property/*)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude results from DBpedia SPARQL query based on URI prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044871/exclude-results-from-dbpedia-sparql-query-based-on-uri-prefix)

Comment: The question of which this is a duplicate is looking  to _exclude_ results that begin with a particular IRI, and so uses a filter `FILTER ( !strstarts(str(?concept), "http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/") )`.  Here you only want ones beginning with a particular IRI, so you'd use `FILTER ( strstarts(str(?property), "http://dbpedia.org/property/") )`.

Comment: Also note that you'll only be keeping the DBpedia infobox properties.  You might want to keep the DBpedia ontology properties too.  They begin with `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/`, and the values for those is much "cleaner".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get one particular property:

```
SELECT ?o { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Albert_Einstein> <http://dbpedia.org/property/...> ?o }
```

or to get all properties beginning with `http://dbpedia.org/property/`

```
SELECT ?p ?o { 
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Albert_Einstein> ?p ?o .
  FILTER(STRSTARTS(str(?p), "http://dbpedia.org/property/")))
}
```