# filter out certain properties from sparql query result

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to filter out certain properties (e.g `dbpprop:` ones) from the result of a sparql query. I'm querying dbpedia sparql endoint.

More precisely what I'd like to do is expressed by the following pseudo code :

```
quantity_of_interest, property, value, property_type = sparqlQuery(query)
if property_type == rdf:Property:
    pass
else:
    return quantity_of_interest, property, value
```

For now, I filter out the properties afterwards in some python code and I use the following sparql query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?qoi ?property ?value (bif:either(?type=rdf:Property, 0, 1) as ?filter_out) 
WHERE { 
    ?qoi a foaf:Person. ?qoi ?property ?value. 
    OPTIONAL{?property rdf:type ?type }
}
```

If `filter_out == 0` I discard the whole result.

Is there a way I can directly make a sparql query which filters out the whole result whenever `?type == rdf:Property` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude results from DBpedia SPARQL query based on URI prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044871/exclude-results-from-dbpedia-sparql-query-based-on-uri-prefix)

Comment: The linked duplicate excludes properties based on a prefix, but the same approach works here, only using an even simpler test.  You just need to use `filter( ?type != rdf:Property )`.

Comment: Oh, I misread the question a little bit;  the answer to the possible duplicate actually goes father than you need, but the sample code in the _question_ shows how to do what you want to do.

Comment: I don't think so, because I'd like to keep properties which have no rdf:type (such as foaf properties)

Comment: I don't think the `filter not exists` is a great solution in this case, since you'll lose results unexpectedly in the future if more `p rdf:type rdf:Property` triples are added.  On the otherhand, if you simply filter out properties prefixed with `dbpprop:`, you won't lose things unexpectedly.  I've written up this point in an answer.

Comment: Duplicated on answers.semanticweb.com: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/26625/filter-out-certain-properties-from-sparql-query-result

Comment: Is that a problem to ask a question in different places ?

Answer (score 1):

This one is working for me at http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?qoi ?property ?value
WHERE { 
    ?qoi a foaf:Person. 
    ?qoi ?property ?value. 
OPTIONAL{ 
    ?property rdf:type ?type 
FILTER( ?type != "rdf:Property" ) }
}
LIMIT 100
```

I am not sure if this is the answer you are looking for

Comment: Not exactly because this query filters out properties which have no rdf:type. Yet I want to keep the results associated with properties with no rdf:type

Comment: @rlkrlk This should work if the `filter` is moved _inside_ the optional pattern:  `optional { ?property rdf:type ?type filter( ?type != rdf:Property ) }`.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor No it does not, it does not bind any value to ?type that's all. Have a look at this [query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fqoi+%3Fproperty+%3Fvalue%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++++%3Fqoi+a+foaf%3APerson.+%0D%0A++++%3Fqoi+%3Fproperty+%3Fvalue.+%0D%0A++++OPTIONAL%7B%3Fproperty+rdf%3Atype+%3Ftype.+FILTER+%28+%3Ftype+%21%3D+rdf%3AProperty+%29+%7D%0D%0A++++%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on) you get properties such as [dbpprop:after](http://dbpedia.org/property/after) whose type is rdf:Property

Comment: @rlkrlk I see your query results, but I can't tell what the query that you ran was (I know it's embedded in the URL, but I'm not going to try to decode it).  The query in this question may bind values for `?type`, but you're not going to see it, because only `?qoi ?property ?value` are `select`ed.   Perhaps you want `SELECT DISTINCT ?qoi ?property ?value ?type`?

Comment: @rlkrlk But also note that what this optional is doing is getting additional information about `?property`;  it's not excluding values of `?property` that have a `rdf:type <something>`.  For that you'd need something like a `filter not exists { … }`.

Comment: That's it, `filter not exists{?property rdf:type rdf:Property}` works fine. Someone answered me on answers.semanticweb.com

Comment: @rlkrlk It's not a great solution, since each property can be _inferred_ to be a `rdf:Property`, since it is, in fact, a property.  Furthermore, on DBpedia, there are no properties declared as `rdf:Property`s that don't also begin with the `dbpprop:` prefix.  (E.g., test with the query  `select ?p { ?p a rdf:Property . filter( !strstarts( str(?p), str(dbpprop:) ) ) }`;  there are no results—there are no properties declared as `rdf:Property`s except the `dbpprop:` properties.  Filtering on the prefix will have a clearer intent, and won't break if RDFS inference is applied.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor There should be some kind of federated query (or maybe it is due to inference) since when I use dbpedia's sparql endpoint with your query within a python's script (`r = urllib2.urlopen('http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?query=select%20%3Fp%20%7B%20%3Fp%20a%20rdf%3AProperty%20.%20filter(%20!strstarts(%20str(%3Fp)%2C%20str(dbpprop%3A)%20)%20)%20%7D&format=json')`)
I have several properties which come up when I consume `r`...

Answer (score 1):

### You can filter out `dbprop:` properties,

> I'm trying to filter out certain properties (e.g., `dbpprop:` ones) from
>   the result of a SPARQL query. I'm querying the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint.

If you're binding properties in your result set, and you want to exclude ones whose URI begins with the `dbpprop:` prefix, you can do that with

```
filter(!strstarts(str(?p),str(dbpprop:)))
```

### or you can filter out properties that don't have type `rdf:Property`.

Your pseudocode looks like it's doing something slightly different though:

```
quantity_of_interest, property, value, property_type = sparqlQuery(query)
if property_type == rdf:Property:
    pass
else:
    return quantity_of_interest, property, value
```

Every property could have the type `rdf:Property`, since it's the class of RDF properties.  DBpedia might not *have* the triple

> ```
> p rdf:type rdf:Property
> ```

for each property `p`, of course, so you may still be able to filter things out like this.  If that's what you want to do, you can do it with `filter not exists { … }`:

```
filter not exists { ?p rdf:type rdf:Property }
```

### For DBpedia, it's the same right now,

As it turns out, these will have the same effect on DBpedia, since there are no properties that have type `rdf:Property` and *aren't* also `dbpprop:` properties;  the following query returns `0`:

```
select (count(*) as ?num) where {
 ?p a rdf:Property
 filter( !strstarts( str(?p), str(dbpprop:) ) )
}
limit 100
```

### but one option is more future compatible.

I'd strongly suggest using the `strstarts` filter rather than the `not exist` here, though.  While the URI of a property can't change over time (i.e., a URI is constant), the triples about it can change.  Thus, if you filter out `dbpprop:` properties, then you'll never accidentally filter out more than you're expecting.  However, if you filter out things that have `rdf:Property` as a type, then you can easily lose results in the future if more `p rdf:type rdf:Property` triples are added (and it seems like such an addition would be logically compatible).

Comment: There should be some kind of federated query (or maybe it is due to inference) since when I use dbpedia's sparql endpoint with your query within a python's script (`r = urllib2.urlopen('http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?query=select%20%3Fp%20%7B%20%3Fp%20a‌​%20rdf%3AProperty%20.%20filter(%20!strstarts(%20str(%3Fp)%2C%20str(dbpprop%3A)%20‌​)%20)%20%7D&format=json')`) I have several properties which come up when I consume `r`...