# Filtering based on a URI in SParQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, linked-data, linkedmdb

You can run the query below at the [Linked MDB SPARQL Explorer](http://www.linkedmdb.org/snorql/). The values of `?imdbID` (the last variable) contains IRIs from one of three possible domains (freebase.com, rottentomatoes.com or imdb.com). I would like to know how to apply a `filter` such that only the rows from the imdb.com domain are retained.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX movie: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/>

SELECT ?title ?date ?director ?imdbID 
WHERE {
 ?film foaf:page ?imdbID.  
 ?film dc:title ?title.
 ?film dc:date ?date .
 ?film movie:director ?directorURI.
 ?directorURI rdfs:label ?director .
}
```

Comment: Does the technique in [Exclude results from DBpedia SPARQL query based on URI prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19044871/1281433) work for you?  With it, you'd just `FILTER ( strstarts(str(?imdbID), "http://imdb.com") )`, I think.

Comment: Oh, the linkedMDB endpoint doesn't support SPARQL 1.1, so you'll have to use regex, it appears: `filter( regex( str(?imdbID), "^http://www.imdb.com" ) )`.  That approach is also listed in the other question.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why this wasn't posted by @JoshuaTaylor as an answer but adding @JoshuaTaylor's filter to your query is what you are requesting:

```sql
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX movie: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/>

SELECT ?title ?date ?director ?imdbID 
WHERE {
 ?film foaf:page ?imdbID.  
 ?film dc:title ?title.
 ?film dc:date ?date .
 ?film movie:director ?directorURI.
 ?directorURI rdfs:label ?director .
 FILTER(regex(str(?imdbID), "www.imdb.com" ) )
}
```

Which returns:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sparql
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" >
  <head>
    <variable name="title"/>
    <variable name="date"/>
    <variable name="director"/>
    <variable name="imdbID"/>
  </head>
  <results>
    <result>
      <binding name="title">
        <literal>Buffy the Vampire Slayer</literal>
      </binding>
      <binding name="date">
        <literal>1992-07-31</literal>
      </binding>
      <binding name="director">
        <literal>Fran Rubel Kuzui (Director)</literal>
      </binding>
      <binding name="imdbID">
        <uri>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103893</uri>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="title">
        <literal>Batman</literal>
      </binding>
      <binding name="date">
        <literal>1989-06-23</literal>
      </binding>
      <binding name="director">
        <literal>Tim Burton (Director)</literal>
      </binding>
      <binding name="imdbID">
        <uri>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096895</uri>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="title">
        <literal>Batman</literal>
      </binding>
      <binding name="date">
        <literal>1966-07-30</literal>
      </binding>
      <binding name="director">
        <literal>Leslie H. Martinson (Director)</literal>
      </binding>
      <binding name="imdbID">
        <uri>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060153</uri>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="title">
        <literal>Batman &amp; Robin</literal>
      </binding>
      <binding name="date">
        <literal>1997-06-20</literal>
      </binding>
      <binding name="director">
        <literal>Joel Schumacher (Director)</literal>
      </binding>
      <binding name="imdbID">
        <uri>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118688</uri>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="title">
        <literal>Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb</literal>
      </binding>
```

If you want to make it case insensitive you can use the `i` flag like so:

```
FILTER(regex(str(?imdbID), "www.IMDB.com", "i" )
```

If you want to see some more information on filter have a look at [3.1 Restricting the Values of Strings](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#restrictString).

Comment: **Not sure why this wasn't posted by @JoshuaTaylor as an answer** I didn't post it, because if this approach works for OP, then this question should be closed as a duplicate of that question (since this technique was presented in the answer to that question).