# Retrieving the wider dbpedia vocabulary for tagging pictures

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to develop a tool in JS for tagging pictures, so I need a set of possible "things" from dbpedia. I already tryed to retrieve this way:

```
select ?s ?l {
   ?s a owl:Class .
   ?s rdf:type ?l
   FILTER regex(str(?s), "House", "i").
}
```

http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=select+%3Fs+%3Fl+%7B%0D%0A+++%3Fs+a+owl%3AClass+.%0D%0A+++%3Fs+rdf%3Atype+%3Fl%0D%0A+++FILTER+regex%28str%28%3Fs%29%2C+%22House%22%2C+%22i%22%29.%0D%0A%7D

And also this way:

```
select ?label 
WHERE {
  ?concept a skos:Concept.
  ?concept skos:prefLabel ?label.
  FILTER regex(str(?label), "^House", "i").
}
```

http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=select+%3Flabel+%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fconcept+a+skos%3AConcept.%0D%0A++%3Fconcept+skos%3AprefLabel+%3Flabel.%0D%0A++FILTER+regex%28str%28%3Flabel%29%2C+%22%5EHouse%22%2C+%22i%22%29.%0D%0A%7D

In the first case, I just have "instances" of the house "thing", but not the "House" class itself. In the second one, I never retrieve the "house" and the similar thing is "houses". Any alternative for retrieving a better vocabulary based in dbpedia dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't bother to restrict yourself to **owl:Thing** or to **skos:Concept**, you can just get things that have a label that contains "house".  Rather than using **regex**, I chose to use **contains** and **lcase**, since a string containment could be less expensive than invoking a full regular expression processor.

```sql
select ?thing ?label where {
 ?thing rdfs:label ?label .
 filter contains(lcase(?label), "house")
}
```

[SPARQL results (limited to 200)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fthing%20%3Flabel%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%3Fthing%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0D%0A%20filter%20contains%28lcase%28%3Flabel%29%2C%20%22house%22%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%20200%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Thanks Joshua, and what if you want to limit it to dbpedia:ontology/XXX results? I thought about it but doesn't work:
http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=select+*+where+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fthing+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.%0D%0A++%3Fthing+rdfs%3AisDefinedBy+%3Fdef.+%0D%0A++filter+contains%28lcase%28%3Flabel%29%2C+%22house%22%29%0D%0A%7D+limit+10

Comment: I think I got it, but not sure if the efficient way: http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=select+*+where+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fthing+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.%0D%0A++%3Fthing+rdfs%3Adomain+%3Fdomain.+%0D%0A++filter+contains%28lcase%28str%28%3Fdomain%29%29%2C+%22ontology%22%29.%0D%0A++filter+contains%28lcase%28%3Flabel%29%2C+%22house%22%29%0D%0A%7D+limit+10

Comment: @gal007 Have a look at your comments again.  Are those supposed to be links?

Comment: If you're also asking for an rdfs:domain of the thing, then you'll probably only get properties back, since rdfs:domain is used to declare the domain of a property.  When you say "dbpedia:ontology/XXX" results, are you asking for properties, or classes, or what?

Comment: @gal007 If you want to filter based on "namespace", have a look at [Exclude results from DBpedia SPARQL query based on URI prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044871/exclude-results-from-dbpedia-sparql-query-based-on-uri-prefix).